# GameScene Deleted Itself

Tags: swift, xcode

Something bad happened to my sprite kit project. I was working on my first ios game, and I've got most of it done. But then today, I somehow see that my game scene swift file was gone. There is no way that I can open or have the file back on the project again. The file marked in red in the picture is the missing file.

[Screen Shot of Xcode project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqS7s.png)

Some one Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

### Time Machine

Use Time Machine (use Spotlight Search) to go back in time to when it wasn't deleted.

### Source Control

If created, go into your source control provider (XCode, BitBucket, GitHub, etc) and make a pull request from a previous commit.

### Snapshots

If you snapshotted the project, go back through them to find when it wasn't deleted.

### Finder

Check all the files inside of where you saved the file. It is possible you only removed the `reference` of the file and not deleted it. Use spotlight search if necessary. Check the `Trash` bin on Mac.

### Tips For Future Projects

Use source control, such as ButBucket or GitHub. XCode has a built in one as well. You can also use Time Machine, a built-in app that captures everything on your mac every couple of hours so you can go back in time and pull anything you need back (even trashed items).